# Multi array into single arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a solution to split this array into single arrays?

Like:
['userfile1'] = array (name => everybodytalkings.jpg) etc.
['userfile2'] = array (name => glove.png) etc.

Trying to solve a problem, that has been going on for 3 hours, and it down to this.
Really hope someone can help me

```
[userfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => everybodytalkings.jpg
                [1] => glove.png
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => image/jpeg
                [1] => image/png
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => /home/christiant.wi8/tmp/phpNmvGeZ
                [1] => /home/christiant.wi8/tmp/phpGjsRrl
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 65188
                [1] => 75182
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, if this is what you're looking for (your "*etc.*" is not very precise). But try

```
$new = array();

foreach($userfile as $key => $item) {
    $new['userfile1'][$key] = $item[0];
    $new['userfile2'][$key] = $item[1];
}
```

Will give you

```
Array
(
    [userfile1] => Array
        (
            [name] => everybodytalkings.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /home/christiant.wi8/tmp/phpNmvGeZ
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 65188
        )

    [userfile2] => Array
        (
            [name] => glove.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /home/christiant.wi8/tmp/phpGjsRrl
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 75182
        )

)
```

See [example](http://3v4l.org/3GNPC).